# Comparing arguments and file text (if clause)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a simple txt file with some info, like this:

```
"John;23124;Firefighter;john@gmail.com"
"Hannah;34241;Hairdresser;hannah@gmail.com"
```

What I wanna do is to represent an if statement with the comparison between my given arguments and check if those arguments are equal to any line in the file text. For example ("John" 23124 "Firefighter" "john@gmail.com") are the arguments I give and they match the first line in the file.

I tried `if[(cat filename.txt | grep $2 | wc -l) - gt 0]` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `if grep -q "$2" filename.txt; then`

Comment: Should the search for a match succeed if _all_ the arguments are found in the same line of the file? And, if so, is their order relevant? Or _any_ of them? Are the arguments supposed to be regular expressions or should they match literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `awk`.
If your file is separated by `;`, you have to add `-F ';'` argument.

```
cat yourfile | awk -F ';' '{print ($2>30000)? "foo" : "bar"}'
```

prints `bar` for the first line (too low argument)
and `foo` for the second one.

If you only want to check if `$2` exists, you can do:

```
cat yourfile | awk -F ';' '{print $2? "foo" : "bar"}'
```

If you want to know how many lines have a specific pattern:

```
cat yourfile | awk -F ';' '{printf("%s", $2? "foo\n" : "")}' | wc -l
```

Then you can use it in conditions like:

```
[ $(cat yourfile | awk -F ';' '{printf("%s", $2? "foo\n" : "")}' | wc -l) -gt 2 ] \
&& echo "at least 2 matches" \
|| echo "less than 2 matches"
```

Or if you prefer `if` statement:

```
if [ $(cat yourfile | awk -F ';' '{printf("%s", $2? "foo\n" : "")}' | wc -l) -gt 2 ];
then
    echo "at least 2 matches"
else
    echo "less than 2 matches";
fi
```